# Using RegEx to find characters inside of two special chars

Tags: typescript

I'm basically trying to get a special set of string characters between some special chars (`'`).

I've tried using `/^'[a-zA-Z]$'/g` but that didn't work as intended..

```js
let keyword = args.slice(1).join(' ').match(/^(')[a-zA-Z]$(')/g)
```

I want the output to be so it reads for example `'hello world'` from `j!prune --contains 'hello world'`
But, everytime I do it, it returns `null`.

**Issue fixed**:
I managed to get a regex that does what I wanted: `/'[^$]+'/g`.

Comment: Can you specify this more clearly? What are values of your `args` in the code snippet?

Comment: I've fixed it, _as you can see by the edit_ , it was pretty dumb of me not to think of that, haha. Sorry for wasting your time